# Multiplying Elements in a List Containing Pairs

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, multiplication

I'm trying to write a code (function) using Scheme that:

- Takes a list of any size as a parameter
- Multiplies every number of the list together
- Symbols should be skipped over
- Values inside pairs should be included in multiplication

In other words, results should be as follows:

```
> (mult '(1 2 3))
6
> (mult '(1 2 x 3 4))
24
> (mult '(1 2 z (3 y 4)))
24 (mine gives me 2)
```

My code allows me to skip over the symbols and multiply everything.  However, once I include a pair inside the list, it acts as though it isn't a number, therefore acting like it doesn't exist.  Here's my code:

```
(define mult
       (lambda (x)
               (if (null? x)
                      1
                      (if(number? (car x))
                         (* (car x) (mult (cdr x)))
                         (mult(cdr x))))))
```

I've tried to use append when it finds a pair, but clearly I did it wrong... Any help on how I could get it to include the values inside a pair would be much appreciated.

i.e. '(1 2 y (3 z 4) = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4

Comment: how deeply nested can the pairs go? is it possible to have a list such as this? `'(((1)) 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, just missing the list? test:

```
(define (mult lst)
  (if (null? lst) 
      1
      (let ((ca (car lst)))
        (cond
          ((number? ca) (* ca (mult (cdr lst))))
          ((list? ca)   (* (mult ca) (mult (cdr lst))))
          (else         (mult (cdr lst)))))))
```

**EDIT**

He're an equivalent version without let:

```
(define (mult lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)         1)
    ((number? (car lst)) (* (car lst) (mult (cdr lst))))
    ((cons? (car lst))   (* (mult (car lst)) (mult (cdr lst))))
    (else                (mult (cdr lst)))))
```

As you see, (car lst) is likely to be evaluated more than once, so I used let in the first version to avoid this.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I had to change "list?" to "cons?" though, because apparently it doesn't recognize list? as a function and... I think "cons?" does the same thing (correct me if I'm wrong). It seems to be what we've been using to declare a list.  But yeah, having that "ca" there for the list multiplication I think was the big part.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Sean The way you write "that ca" makes me think this part remains obscure to you. I edited my post for a maybe clearer version without let.

Answer (score 0):

It is a slightly advanced technique but this problem can easily be formulated as a tail recursive algorithm.

```
(define (mult lst)
  (let multiplying ((lst lst) (r 1))   ; r is the multiplicative identity...
    (if (null? lst)
        r
        (let ((next (car lst))
              (rest (cdr lst)))
          (multiplying rest (cond ((number? next) (* next r))
                                  ((list?   next) (* (mult next) r))
                                  (else           r)))))))
> (mult '(1 2 3 a b (((((10)))))))
60
```

Using tail recursion has performance implications but, admittedly, it is not the first thing to learn - recursion is.  However, in this case, because lists are often very long, avoiding a stack frame for each list element can be a dramatic savings; using tail calls avoids the stack frame.